# What is struct Cleaner <T*> mean?

Tags: c++, generics

*What is `struct Cleaner <T*>` mean?  Is it specific the second Cleaner can only accept the type of pointer? what is the terminology of this usage in C++?*

```cpp
template <typename T> struct Cleaner {
   static void clean ( T x ) { 
   }
};

template <typename T> struct Cleaner<T*> {
   static void clean ( T* x ) {
      if ( x ) { delete x; } 
   }
};

template <typename T> void release ( T x ) { Cleaner<T>::clean ( x ); }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization

Comment: why not use `release` itself?

Comment: @appleapple I am learning data structure, I am trying to write an STL of myself for practice. Thanks for your edit.

Comment: @LexssamaLi  Just a note that, for the code you provide, you can simply specialize `release` by `template<typename T> void release(T*){}`, no need for a seperate `Cleaner<T>`

Comment: @appleapple Yes indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to provide two behaviours for the function `release()` depending on the type of its argument (pointer or not).

We could also have written two overloads

```
template <typename T> void release2(T) { }
template <typename T> void release2(T *x) { delete x; }
```

In your example, the distinction is done on two versions of the `Cleaner` helper type (partial specialisation, as stated in the comment) but the idea is the same.

In C++17 we could also written a more concise version

```
#include <trait_types>

template <typename T> void release3(T x) {
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
        delete x;
    }
}
```

When it comes to the usage

```
int
main()
{
  int i=12;
  int *pi=new int(23);
  release3(i);  // NO delete
  release3(pi); // delete is used
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the null check before `delete` is not necessary (it's done internally, as with `free()` in C).

Answer (score 0):

First, you defined a class template named Cleaner.

Second, you "partially specialized" the class template for T*, so that if T is a pointer type, it will create the specialized version of "clean()".

In this case, at compile-time, if T is a pointer type, the Cleaner<> template will use the second patter, while if T is a fully qualified type, it will use the original.